# what address do I need to have to host a restful WCF service publicly off my computer?

Tags: wcf, rest, uri

I have allready built a wcf web service and am having it work great on my local mashine by using my private IP address. However when I attempt to access it on another network the browser fails to connect. I understand that there is a public IP address and have tried switching over to it but with that both my own computer and computers on other networks have failed.

The code I am using is:

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(serviceSetup), new Uri("http://PublicIp:8000"));
ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(serviceContract), new WebHttpBinding(), "/");
ep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
host.Open();
/*
WebServiceHost myHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(serviceSetup), new Uri("http://PrivateIP:8000"));
ServiceEndpoint myep = myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(serviceContract), new WebHttpBinding(), "/");
myep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
myHost.Open();
*/
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a non-code problem like a firewall block? Or do I not understand something about IP addresses?

Comment: On the same local network? or through the internet?

Comment: When I say another computer, I mean another nerwork entirly.

Comment: Two things you could have a firewall issue on the router or the pc though if it works locally you should be ok on the pc. The most probable answer is you need to [map port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) 8000 in the router to the local ip address of the pc your webservice is on.

Comment: Hey thanks alot, Ill try that out. If it works that should go up as the answer too.

Comment: The problem was that I was behind a router which blocked my computer from hosting on the public IP address. The solution was to map a port on my router to my computer so that my app could pick up incoming requests. Big thanks to Mark Hall who pointed me in the right direction in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was behind a router which blocked my computer from hosting on the public IP address. The solution was to map a port on my router to my computer so that my app could pick up incoming requests. Big thanks to Mark Hall who pointed me in the right direction in the comments.